# Storage Linking Issue in Laravel 8 on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, upload, localhost, laravel-8

- Laravel Version: 8.35.1
- PHP Version: 8.0.0

**Description:**

I'm uploading an image with laravel using this code:

```
$product_image = $request->file('product_image');
$product_image_extension = $product_image->extension();
$product_image_name = time() . '.' . $product_image_extension;
$product_image->storeAs('/media/product_images', $product_image_name);
$model->product_image = $product_image_name;
```

It works fine, the file is uploaded to storage/app/media/product_images/.

Then, I run the command

> php artisan storage: link

to create the symlink in public.
The Command Execute Like this:

```
Local NTFS volumes are required to complete the operation.
The [E:\Complete Programming Bootcamp\laravel Work\ecom-project\cyber_shopping\public\storage] link 
has been connected to [E:\Complete Programming Bootcamp\laravel Work\ecom- 
project\cyber_shopping\storage\app/public].
The links have been created.
```

I am Using This Code To Display Image:

```
{{asset('storage/media/product_images/' . $list->product_image)}}
```

But Image is not displaying on the frontend.

Also, The Storage Folder Is not created in the public folder.
PLz, Help Me.

Thanks

Comment: try to access that image directly from browser, does the image accessible from that url?

Comment: yes, I try this but the page not found error occurs. When I Copy the storage/app/public/[media(this folder)]  paste it in the public/storage(created by myself) folder the images displayed. But This process is not dynamic. I need that when I upload an image it also stores in the public/storage folder and the display.

Comment: Try this rm -rf public/storage Then run php artisan storage:link

Comment: I try this, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Everything works fine. The issue is 1) images are stored in the storage/app/public/media folder but not in the public/storage folder. 2) There is no folder in public with name storage after execution of `php artisan storage: link`. When I copy all images from storage/app/public/media and paste them in public/storage(created by myself)/media/ Then all images display this process is static i want to do it dynamically. i tried many queries but it not works.

Comment: You have to store the files under `storage/app/public/media/product_images/` to make them publicly accessibles through `asset('storage/media/product_images/' . $list->product_image)`. So change `$product_image->storeAs('/media/product_images', $product_image_name);` to ` $product_image->storeAs('public/media/product_images', $product_image_name);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/photoncms/cms/issues/8, you are trying to symlink on fat32 drive on which it does not work. Try to test it on NTFS drive

Comment: Thanks, This Problem is solved by running the command `php artisan storage:link` on the NTFS drive. Now Everythings Goes Right.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:: Store Image

```
$path = ‘’;
if( $request->has('product_image') ) {
    $path = $request->file('product_image')->store('media/product_images');
}
$model->product_image = $path;
```

Step 2:: Check Store File Path

The File Will Be Store In Path::

————————————————————————————————

```
Storage/app/public/media/product_images/
```

Step 3:: Link Storage In Public Folder

Run The Storage Link Command and remove storage link folder from the public if already exist

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Step 4:: Create Global Function To Access Images Main Controller.php File Create Global Storage Image Getting Function Like This

```
public static function getUrl($path)
{
    $url = "";
    if( !empty($path) && Storage::disk('public')->exists($path) )
        $url = Storage::url($path);
    return $url;
}
```

Step 5:: Use Function In Assest To Display Image

```
<img src="{{ getUrl($list->product_image) }}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Brother To Help Me. But Image is Still Not Found

Comment: what is the image src path?

Comment: {{asset('storage/media/product_images/' . $list->product_image)}}  => admin/storage/media/product_images/shirt.png